# nested ng-repeat with 2 json data sources

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is going to be complicated to explain, so please bear with me.

The task: To repeat json data in a table. (list of products, last cell is a button).

The problem: On clicking the button, another repeated list of rows appears under the product (second data-repeat, accessories of the products) but must match the product.

Now i can get the first part. I can even ng-repeat the second part, and the ng-click. However, every button repeats the same thing. I know that $index probably can be used here, i just dont understand how.

So how do i get the accessories for each individual product, to only show when the product button is clicked?

Example: Product 1 has 5 accessories. Product 2 has 1 accessory. If i click the product 1's button, 5 accessories show underneath it. If i click the product 2's button, 1 accessory shows below it.

Code:

```
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:0px;">
                <table class="table table-bordered" ng-controller="tableCtrl_1" ng-switch="test">
                    <tr style="height:70px;background-color:#0C4791;">
                        <th style="text-align:center;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">Flexi Floor/Low Wall</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">Cooling</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">Heating</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">Nominal Capacities(cooling/heating)</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">Pipe Length</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">List Price</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;color:white;vertical-align:middle;">Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat-start = "getdata in getdata | filter:'Flexi Floor/Low Wall':true">
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">{{getdata.model_no_from}} + {{getdata.model_no_to}}</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">{{getdata.cooling}}</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">{{getdata.heating}}</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;"><span style="color:blue">{{getdata.nominal_cooling}}</span><span style="color:red;">{{getdata.nominal_heating}}</span></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">{{getdata.pipe_length}}</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">{{getdata.system_listPrice | currency: "£"}}</span></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;"><button class="btn btn-default btn-large btn-block" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">Select</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showDetails }" >
                        <!--<td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">{{getdata_2.sales_description}}</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">{{getdata_2.list_price}}</td> -->
                        <td colspan="7" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;">test 1</td>

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the controller:

```
 testApp.controller('tableCtrl_1', function($scope, $http, ajaxServices, secondaryServices){
        getdata();
        function getdata(){
            $http.post("angular_data.php").success(function(data){
            $scope.getdata = data;
            });
        };


        ajaxServices.getProducts().success(function(data){
            $scope.getdata = data
        });

        secondaryServices.getProducts_2().success(function(data){
            $scope.getdata_2 = data
        });
```

});

Services:

```
 testApp.factory('ajaxServices', function($http){
return {
    getProducts: function(){
        return $http.get('angular_data.php', {data: {}})
    }
}
});

 testApp.factory('secondaryServices', function($http){
return {
    getProducts_2: function(){
        return $http.get('angular_data_2.php', {data: {}})
    }
}
});
```

Pardon the inline-styling, just easier for me while testing.

Comment: try "getdata in getdata track by $index" where $index will be unique key value. Also you've used a single variable "showdetails" for toggling, which may not work in these situations. Try something like showdetails_{{$index}}. Instead of using ng-class, try ng-if which should show your tr value only when the index is clicked and that showdetails_{{$index}} value is set.

Comment: I dont understand the clarification?

Comment: You've used "getdata in getdata" in ngRepeat. Is it working fine?

Comment: Yes it works fine. Probably shouldnt, but it does.

Comment: I should clarify as well, that after ng-repeat end, there is a class there. I originally had it repeat the secondary data, but for testing purposes, i was just try to get it to show something different.

Comment: Try modifying this plnkr and check with your functionality: http://plnkr.co/edit/9vuNe58dS8uHadVDdZBT

Comment: This works fine, except for the second ng-repeat on the td. This would only repeat 1 td, where some products have multiple accessories. So i think I would need the second repeat on the tr, then filter the data from json somehow. Like if product1, then acc1,2,3,4. if product2, acc1,2. Etc.

Comment: Check whether this is your expected output http://plnkr.co/edit/9vuNe58dS8uHadVDdZBT?p=preview

Comment: that looks like how i would want it yes. From a single data array. But i am pulling from 2 php scripts that encode into json.

Comment: Fine. Then try combining two JSON output to single JSON input. If product and accessories have relationships, then it should the better way. Use angular.forEach() for combining both JSON. It should work.

Comment: I will work on that and get back to you. thank you very much.